# How is the Twilio 'ConferenceSid' generated?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-twiml

Here is the code from Twilio Docs - Python

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "AC0edc1a7f12e0e0876ce878e903d3bd54"
auth_token = "{{ auth_token }}"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
conference = client.conferences.get("CFbbe46ff1274e283f7e3ac1df0072ab39")
print conference.status
```

I am trying to create  conference call instance. I have everything working except for the conference call instance. Ideally I would like for hosts to enter a pin and listeners to join the conference by pressing a digit. But right now, I am trying to create a conference instance. I do not under stand from the above docs, how do I create the 34-key conference sid? I am assuming this is automatically generated? How could I store this value?

```
@app.route('/caller', methods=['GET','POST']) #'GET'
def caller():
    response = twiml.Response()
    response.say("Welcome to the conference call.")
    response.pause(length = "1")
    response.say ("Please hold.")
    conference()

    return str(response)

def conference():
    client = TwilioRestClient(settings.api_key, settings.api_tok)
    conference = client.conferences.get(ConferenceSid)
    #print /2010-04-01/Accounts/settings.api_key/Conferences/{ConferenceSid}
```

Comment: Could an answer in python please be given -  Should I be using the Dial verb to create a conference?

Answer (score 3):

As per [Twilio's documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#examples-1), it seems like you're not really supposed to return the conference's SID to create one.

You're supposed to provide a conference name instead:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

The SID may be useful later on if you also need to call the API. If you actually need it, you should be able to get a list of conferences.

Comment: [Twilio Moderated Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/moderated-conference) How does the `menu.php` file relate to the `listener.xml` file? If a user were to press `2` how does the `menu.php` script redirect the code to run on the xml file? Is is possible to create an xml-only version of this press 1,2,3 app? I have made an `xml script` similar to the docs but if a user presses a digit how could I redirect them to a separate xml file to run the code represented through the digit pressed?